# Getting a div to show if an input value's length is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, keyup

I am trying to run a simple `if-statement` that checks if the input's value (what is typed in) is at least 5 and then to show the submit button. I tried using the `keyup` function to detect the value as it is being typed in.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
$('#submit-package').hide();
$('#package-name-input').on('keyup', function() {
  var nameInput = $(this).val().length;
  if (nameInput => 5) {
    $('#submit-package').fadeBoolToggle();
  }
  //$('#package-name-input').val().fadeBoolToggle(length > 5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="gen-input" id="package-name-input">
<div class="proceed-btn sans-pro" id="submit-package">
  <span class="proceed-btn-text">SUBMIT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `fadeBoolToggle` waits for an argument which you're never passing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass condition as your function parameter, also you should change `=>` to `>=`

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
  return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
}
$('#submit-package').hide();
$('#package-name-input').on('keyup', function() {
  var nameInput = $(this).val().length;
  $('#submit-package').fadeBoolToggle(nameInput >= 5);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="gen-input" id="package-name-input">
<div class="proceed-btn sans-pro" id="submit-package">
  <span class="proceed-btn-text">SUBMIT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I guess my commented out code that I tried first was closer than the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

use `keyup()` method

```js
var i = 0;    
$('#target').hide();
$('#text').keyup(function(event) {
    i++;
    if(i == 5)
    {
        $('#target').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="text">
<div id="target">
<input type="button" value="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a syntax error.  Greater than or equal to is expressed as `>=`, not `=>`.